# Finding the right Path

Tags: java, file, io, path

I want to generate a PDF with [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) and put it under `docs/file1.pdf`.  The  folder `docs` is already created, but I don't know how to access it from Java.

My  project structure looks like this:

- `build`
- `nbprojects`
- `docs`
- `src` <-- this is where the generated files belong

  - `java`

    - `generator`

      - `generator.java` <-- this is where the files are being generated
- [some other folders]

When I try:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

I get (I'm on Linux):

```
/home/user1/.netbeans/9.0/config/GF_5.0/domain1/config
```

My guess was going 3 levels up:

```
../../../docs/file1.pdf
```

But it says

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../../../docs/file1.pdf was not found

**Question**: How can I access `docs` from `src/java/generator/generator.java`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use absolute path. Or you can use this print statement to know your current directory as per your java program,

```
System.out.println("Current Dir: " + new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

It will print something like,

```
\pkr\work7\ws\test\.
```

Once you know this path, you can build your path correctly by putting .. and be able to correctly read your file.

Comment: I get exactly the same directory that I had:  `/home/user1/.netbeans/9.0/config/GF_5.0/domain1/config`.

Comment: Where is your docs folder located? Can you give absolute path for docs folder?

Comment: Then you may try ../../../../../NetBeansProjects/project1/docs/file1.pdf but why don't you use absolute path?

Comment: Because it should  also work on different machines. I can't be sure, what paths will be used by other people, if they import my project.

Comment: Then even this relative (or absolute) path may not work on other machines unless they follow a structure just like yours. If others have a path like /home/user1/NetBeansProjects/project222/docs then it will fail for them anyway.

Comment: Best way is, to create your folder docs parallel to config folder in domain1 directory, so you and others can access it like ../docs/file1.pdf and this path will work for all