# How to specify the path relative to some folder in Java?

Tags: java, image, netbeans, path

I am trying to specify the path of an image, and the path of a stylesheet using the following two codes:

```
pane.getStylesheets().add("src\\dbgui\\Style\\CSS\\base.css");
btn_remove.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(Style/Images/add.png)")
```

neither works, i just don't understand how paths works in java, should i specify the path relative to the root folder, or relative to the src folder or relative to what exactly ? because i don't want to use the full path starting by the C: drive, well actually even when i tried this, it didn't work either.

Is there a way to set a relative folder to specify paths from in java ?
I am using Netbeans IDE.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52919689/finding-the-right-path/52919872#52919872

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi thank you

Answer (score 1):

path is specified in the below format -:
(Assuming current file is located in a particular folder)

../               : This goes one step above the current folder

./childFolderName : This goes into a child folder in the current folder **(. refers to current folder)**

../folderName : This goes to a folder inside the parent folder

Comment: Hi Rumando, no i mean relative to what should we specify the url, relative to which folder ?, the root folder or the src folder or what ?
because i got confused

Comment: You have to specify it using currently referring resource. As an example assume you want to add image located in the outside or your source code file folder but in a folder located at parent directory named Images, Then it should be ../Images/ImageName.extension.  I think this resolves your problem.